# script cannot be run from cronjob, but works manually

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

i managed to create a working script to gather information from login protected site which I have membership on, I expect the script to works on cronjob but it doesnt.

is there anything i do wrong here ?

```
#!/bin/bash

COOKIES="kukis.txt"

curl -k -c $COOKIES --data "userid=$(sed -n 1p /home/reza/Videos/.ktsandi.txt)&pass=$(sed -n 2p /home/reza/Videos/.ktsandi.txt)" https://my.smartfren.com/mysmartfren_login/login


LOG="frenlog.html"

until curl 'https://my.smartfren.com/mysmartfren_home'-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/72.0.3626.121 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://my.smartfren.com/mysmartfren_login' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -b $COOKIES -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' &> /dev/stdout | tee -a $LOG
do
  echo "$(date '+%d/%m/%Y') - Failed to run, will retry shortly" >> /home/reza/testfren/skrip.log
done && rm /home/reza/testfren/${COOKIES}

# EMAIL DATA
RECIPIENT="danil.cahyadi@gmail.com"
MAILER="rezanas_tion@gmail.com"
SUBJECT="Info kuota harian Smartfren"

# SORTING...
MAIL="frendata.html"

expDateBonus="16/04/2019 23:59:58"
expDate="05/05/2019 23:59:58"

if [[ $(date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") == $expDateBonus ]] || [[ $(date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") == $expDate ]]
then


    grep -A1 -E "<tr><td width='40%'>Bonus Data</td><td>|<tr><td width='40%'>Midnight Internet</td><td>" $LOG | sed "/--/d" | sed -n '3,4p;7,8p' >> $MAIL

else


    grep -A1 -E "<tr><td width='40%'>Bonus Data</td><td>|<tr><td width='40%'>Midnight Internet</td><td>" $LOG | sed "/--/d" >> $MAIL
fi

#SENDING MAIL

(
  echo To: $RECIPIENT
  echo From: $MAILER
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
  echo Subject: $SUBJECT
  echo Remaining internet quota as of $(date "+%d/%m/%Y")
  echo 
  cat $MAIL
) | sendmail -t && rm $MAIL $LOG
```

Comment: First rule of `cron` jobs: specify full paths to everything; in this case the `$MAIL` file, as well as the executables `curl` and `sendmail`.

Comment: Please include the relevant cron entry, and any error messages (redirect the cron output / error streams to a file, if you are not already doing so)

Comment: i don't have any error file, the script works fine if run on terminal, the problem with cron

Comment: Use full path in $LOG, $MAIL, $COOKIES. Set a full path to executed commands. Redirect output of cronjob by `2>&1 >/tmp/cronjob.log` and check log for errors. Problem not in cron, but in script whats written not for cron but terminal shell

Comment: Read related questions and find same suggestions

Comment: Along with above comments (full paths in script), Have you given absolute path of the script in your cron job entry?

Comment: ... the redirection order should be `>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1`

Comment: using full path for everything command related works ! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is wise to use full path to `curl`, `sendmail` etc to be sure you will access to commands. Second its good to source your bash profile:

```
source /path/to/your/home/.bashrc
```

or

```
. /path/to/your/home/.bashrc
```

and add this right after

```
#!/bin/bash
```